# Java Overide getInputStream from HttpServletRequestWrapper to escape HTML in JSON

Tags: jackson, xss

I am trying to override the HttpServletRequestWrapper#getInputStream(). I am trying to read the JSON in the body and escape the HTML tags to prevent XSS. I am working on a lage application with multiple endpoints. I am using JacksonMapper to translate the JASON to the POJOs so want to sanitize the input before the actual mapping. My code looks as

```
    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, Object> jsonMap = mapper.readValue(super.getInputStream(),
            Map.class);

    for (String key : jsonMap.keySet()) {
        if (jsonMap.get(key) != null) {
            if (jsonMap.get(key).getClass() == String.class)
                jsonMap.put(key, (Object) StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml((String) jsonMap.get(key)));
        }
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(byteOut);
    mapper.writeValue(out, jsonMap);
    final ByteArrayInputStream byteIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(
            byteOut.toByteArray());
    ServletInputStream inputStream = new ServletInputStream() {

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            return byteIn.read();
        }
    };
    return inputStream;
}
```

I am getting a Jackson Mapping exception as below:

```
8:29:20,323 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher] (http-/0.0.0.0:7080-7) Failed executing PUT /portal/api/tenant/2: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ReaderException: 
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('¬' (code 172)): 
expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')                                                                                                                                                                                    
at [Source: com.dell.em.controller.RequestWrapper$1@4ed35486; line: 1, column: 2]                                                                                                                                                                               
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:202) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.6.Final-redhat-1]                                                                                     
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:136) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.6.Final-redhat-1]                                                                                                
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:159) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.6.Final-redhat-1]                                                                                                         
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:269) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.6.Final-redhat-1]                                                                                                         
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:227) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
```

I am not sure where the charecter is coming from. I have a simple json as input:

```
{"id":2,"tenantName":"Test","tenantLogo":null,"address1":"<script>alert(\"o1\")</script>","city":"test","state":"Alabama","zip":"78769","country":"United States","timezone":"US/Central","contactFirstName":"Test","contactLastName":"Test","contactEmail":"Test@rest.com","contactPhone":"9794444444","address2":null,"domainName":null}
```

Comment: It depends on how your client is sending the request. Maybe it's being compressed?

Comment: It wasnt the compression. It seemed like I needed the right encoding  on the new input stream.

Comment: Glad you found the solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone faces the same problem. I had to encode the new InputStream and instead of writeVAlue I needed writeValueAsString to have the quotes around json.

```
@Override
public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    InputStream in = super.getInputStream();
    Map<String, Object> jsonMap = mapper.readValue(in, Map.class);

    for (String key : jsonMap.keySet()) {
        if (jsonMap.get(key) != null) {
            if (jsonMap.get(key).getClass() == String.class)
                jsonMap.put(key, (Object) StringEscapeUtils
                        .escapeHtml((String) jsonMap.get(key)));
        }
    }

    final ByteArrayInputStream byteIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(Charset
            .forName("UTF-16").encode(mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonMap))
            .array());


    ServletInputStream inputStream = new ServletInputStream() {

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            return byteIn.read();
        }
    };

    return inputStream;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the solution of @Rahul Dhar to fit in my case, because I have couple of rest services accepting regular input along with json input (like accept the body as the id of the user)

```
@Override
public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        InputStream in = super.getInputStream();
        String inputString = IOUtils.toString(in, "utf-8");

        if (inputString.contains("{")) {    // is JSON
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Map<String, Object> jsonMap = mapper.readValue(inputString, Map.class);

            for (String key : jsonMap.keySet()) {
                Object value = jsonMap.get(key);
                if (value != null) {
                    if (value.getClass() == String.class)
                        jsonMap.put(key, (Object) stripXSS((String) value)); // (stripXSS is a private method that do spit out xss characters)
                }
            }
            return new CustomServletInputStream(
                    Charset.forName("utf-8").encode(mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonMap)).array());
        } else {
            return new CustomServletInputStream(Charset.forName("utf-8").encode(inputString).array());
        }
}
```